# Can the same controller can be used for MVC and WebApi in asp.net 5 mvc 6?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In MVC 6, it seems both MVC and WebApi controllers are same.
I have the following code

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TeamController : Controller
{

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    static readonly List<Team> _items = new List<Team>()
    {
        new Team { Id = 1, Name = "First Team" }
    };

    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Team> Get()
    {
        return _items;
    }
}
```

I have Index.cshtml under Views/Team folder.
I am able to get the result in localhost:port/api/team, but the localhost:port/Team/Index is returning 404 error.

So how to use the same controller for both MVC and WebApi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the code like this ([blog article linked below](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/02/07/asp-net-5-deep-dive-routing))

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TeamController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("Index")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    static readonly List<Team> _items = new List<Team>()
    {
        new Team { Id = 1, Name = "First Team" }
    };

    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Team> Get()
    {
        return _items;
    }
```

Changed the 'Route' attribute for the class to just [controller] and then add HttpGet to the Index() method which returns the view.

Now http://myComputer:52687/Team/Index returns the view and http://myComputer:52687/Team returns JSON response.

Answer (score 3):

you have the route attribute applied to the class

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TeamController : Controller
```

so it will apply that route part to everything in that controller. you may be better off defining custom routes in app startup instead.

here is a great article covering routing, including a mixed MVC/API controller:
http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/02/07/asp-net-5-deep-dive-routing

Comment: Thanks. The article was super helpful and it is working now.